# Creating Connection Bitbucket with AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repository.
I want pipelines in AzureDevops to build sources when i make a pull request in Bitbucket.

I set up PR trigger in yaml files.
But it did not work when i made a pull request.

I tried to run the pipeline manually, it worked and succeeded.
I guess, bitbucket could not send a message to azure when pull requests are made.

How to set up connection Bitbucket with AzureDevOps?

Comment: How did you set up the PR trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Integration between **BitBucket Cloud** and Azure Pipelines:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

You can specify the target branches when validating your pull requests. For example, to validate pull requests that target `master` and `releases/*`, you can use the following `pr` trigger.

```
pr:
- master
- releases/*
```

This configuration starts a new run the first time a new pull request is created, and after every update made to the pull request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I already wrote pr trigger in yaml like this. 
<code>
pr:
 branches:
   include:
     - '*'
trigger: none

 But it does not work.
And I use this url as as reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#my-pipeline-isnt-triggering

Comment: Do you use `BitBucket Cloud` repo type? Could you share your entire yaml file?